# Pokemon Home Box Sorting

Tags: pokemon-home

I am having issues with keeping my Pokemon in a certain order when using Pokemon Home on the Switch. Each time I transfer Pokemon across from SWSH/SV/BDSP to Pokemon Home, Pokemon Home will re-order and shuffle up my boxes.

---

Here's an example from Scarlet:

> [image: box3]

Box 3 is ordered by local Dex number and different forms (i.e.: family-of-three + family-of-four Maushold) are placed side-by-side.

---

> [image: home]

Initially dragged into Pokemon Home the order is maintained and nothing has been changed or altered.

---

> [image: homeagain]

Saving and quitting and then returning to the box results in the box being totally shuffled up and removes the initial organization that I set.

---

How can I prevent Pokemon Home from disrupting my set organization?

Comment: It's not totally shuffled, they look orderer by national dex

Comment: @pinckerman Fair. But if I want to put them back as they were, it seems like no dice. Are there no sorting options? No way to avoid them being rearranged?

Comment: I don't think so, I don't remember any sorting option.